# iOS/Swift: How to unzip files by importing Github (or else) files manually? Error Domain=SSZipArchiveErrorDomainUserInfo failed to open zip file

Tags: ios, swift, zip, unzip, ssziparchive

I tried to use the [ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) framework for unzipping a zip file, but I don't understand the problem.
It doesn't tell me some error, but I could not find my unzipped files/folders.

```
// Unzip
let sourceURL = localUrl.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: "TEMP.zip")
let destinationURL = localUrl.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: "TEST")
SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: sourceURL, toDestination: destinationURL)
```

EDIT: With the answer above, here is the error message:
**`Error Message: Error Domain=SSZipArchiveErrorDomain Code=-1 "failed to open zip file" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=failed to open zip file}`**

EDIT2:  I checked with the function fileExists, and file is available

```
let str = sourceURL

let url = URL(string: str)
print(url!.path,"\n")

if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url!.path) {
    print("FILE IS AVAILABLE")
} else {
    print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using `unzipFile(atPath:, toDestination:)`, you can use one of the methods that offer error feedback - there are ones with either pointer to error or with completion handler

Comment: @mag_zbc good answer, I have an error message now...

Comment: Are you sure you're using correct zip file name? I would assume both file name and extension are case sensitive.

Comment: @mag_zbc name of the zip file seems good...

Comment: Did you check that file actually exists? For instance, using `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: sourceURL)`?

Comment: @mag_zbc I just checked with your mentionned function, it says that file exists

Comment: @mag_zbc my mistake, it is my fault. I renamed it .zip, but it is a .tar.gz file... Thank you for your help